# How to Map objects inside an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is for a React Native Chat app.

My data should be something like this:

```js
const data = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: John Doe,
   messages: [
     {text: 'Hello', sentAt: 'time here'},
     {text: 'How are you?', sentAt: 'time here'},
     {text: 'Can we meet?', sentAt: 'time here'}
   ]
   image: { uri: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/97.jpg" },
 },
 {
   id: 1,
   name: Robert Smith,
   messages: [
     {text: 'Hi', sentAt: 'time here'},
     {text: 'Can I call now?', sentAt: 'time here'},
   ]
   image: { uri: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/97.jpg" },
 },
 {
   id: 1,
   name: Roy Pinkham,
   messages: [
     {text: 'Please give me a call', sentAt: 'time here'},
   ]
   image: { uri: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/97.jpg" },
 }
]
```

I am listing the Chat list using a FlatList:

```js
<FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <MessageItem
            name={item.name}
            message={item.messages.map((message) => message.text)}
            image={item.image}
            read={item.read} // Hard-coded value in data array
            time={item.time} // hard-coded value in data array
            renderRightActions={() => (
              <MessageDelete onPress={() => deleteMessage(item)} />
            )}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Chats", item)}
          />
        )}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          showSearch && <Search query="" onSearchChange={onSearchChange} />
        }
      />
```

The messages shows like this all stacked up and I am not what is the workaround.
What I am trying to achieve is displaying the last message based on timestamp.

[image]

Comment: maybe message={item.messages[item.messages.length].text} ?

Comment: @fonzane more like `message={item.messages[item.messages.length - 1].text}`

Comment: In your render method, sort the messages by time (descending), then pass the first one to your MessageItem component.

Comment: @OskarZanota that addressed my query, thanks!! Can you please add it as answer so I can mark it. I don't know why people downvote a question here if it's a basic one.

Comment: @Adnomination I just posted the answer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last message of the messages array, set the message attribute of the `MessageItem` element to the last message, like so:

```html
message={item.messages[item.messages.length - 1].text}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want the latest message **only**, you can just pass the value directly into the message for the latest sent one instead of mapping all of it.

```
<...
messages={message={() => this.getLatestMessage(item.messages)}
... />
```

and `getLatestMessage()` should be something like this

```
getLatestMessage = (messages) => {
    message = ...filter latest message logic here

    return message.text;
}
```